# How to use Spark with HiveContext

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am new to spark.I am trying to use HiveContext in Spark SQL to access window functions.But when I give this,

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
```

I get the following error:

> error: object hive is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql

I found out the solution that I need to include the following dependencies in build.sbt file.

```scala
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "1.5.2
```

But I don't know,where should I find this build.sbt file in spark
Should I change in,

```
/home/cloudera/spark-1.5.2/build/sbt
```

(or)

```
/home/cloudera/spark-1.5.2/sbt/sbt
```

(or)

```
/home/cloudera/spark-1.5.2/project/plugins.sbt
```

Please help me to add the dependencies in build.sbt file.

Comment: So, you're trying to build Spark from scratch?

Comment: yes..I am trying to build it from scratch.But before build I need to add the dependencies in build.sbt file.From which folder should I get the build.sbt file in spark?

Answer (score 2):

To build Spark with Hive support there is no need for any changes in build definitions. Just makes sure you activate required profiles

- Maven

  ```
  mvn -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -DskipTests ... clean package
  ```
- SBT

  ```
  build/sbt -Phive -Phive-thriftserver ... assembly
  ```

Adding `spark-hive` as a dependency is required only when you build your own projects.

Also, please not that pre-built (`spark-[SPARK-VERSION]-bin-hadoop[HADOOP-VERSION].tgz` files) binaries available from Spark downloads page are already built with Hive support.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.